# Ruby - I want codes only work on certain condition but not sure how to do it

Tags: ruby, loops

I know I must have missing something on `arr2.each_index` but I can't think of anything else I can add.. my brain is melting lol
The codes below **else** should only be executed when there is **no "num" in arr2** larger then num, but now they are executed whenever there is a "num" in arr2 larger then num. I hope the question makes sense.

```rb
arr = [{"num":1,"head":5},{"num":3,"head":1},{"num":4,"head":1},{"num":5,"head":7}]
arr2 = [{"init1":[{"num":2,"head":1}]},{"init2":[{"num":35,"head":2}]},{"init3":[{"num":98,"head":1}]},{"init4":[{"num":51,"head":1},{"num":77,"head":5}]}]
arr3 = []

puts "Card you want to place outside? "
num = gets.chomp.to_i

def add_card_to_init(arr, arr2, arr3, num)  
  arr.each_with_index do |card, index|
    if card[:num] == num
        catch :skip do
            arr2.each_index do |index|
                x = arr2[index].values[0]
                if num > x[x.length-1][:num]
                  #code
                  puts "num > init"
                else
                  # code only runs when no num > x[x.length-1][:num] 
                  puts "num < init"
                  throw :skip
                end
            end
        end
    end
  end
end

add_card_to_init(arr, arr2, arr3, num)
```

Expect output when num = 3

```rb
num > init
```

But what I got is

```rb
num > init
num < init
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/comment-page-1/) for tips on debugging your program.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Always start a question with a statement of what you are trying to do without reference to your code. An example is often helpful, showing the inputs and desired output (return value).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, thank you so much for the article! I will go and have a read :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for your tips! I have troubles on putting the questions down in words as I still have not much experiences on that. But I do hope I will get better in future..

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be to set a flag "smaller" to `true` before you enter the `each_index` loop and set it to `false` inside the loop if `init >= num`. And then run your code outside the loop based on the flag. That's not elegant but quick and dirty. Optionally you can leave the loop on the first `false` event.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I re-do the codes and I found a way to do it now :)